Identify smd top marking ADLG
Can you please help to identify the 8 pin component with the top marking: ADLG?
It was in an earlier 2020 hardware revision of this circuit:
enter link description here


It is a MP2144GJ (marking ADL) from Monolithic Power Systems.

Picture from LCSC :

